# How to get merge set nested array of list hash map in immutablejs

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

What does this code do?

```
  const repos = state.get(`users/${username}`);
    const nextRepos = repos.concat(Immutable.fromJS(res.body));

    return state.merge({
      [`users/${username}__res`]: res,
      [`users/${username}`]: nextRepos
    });
```

Taken from: https://github.com/quangbuule/redux-example/blob/master/src/js/reducers/Repo.js

How is `get('users/1')` or `merge('users/1')` work.

Ultimately I have this structure:

```
let state = {
  sequence: [
    [{column:3}],
    [{column: 3}]
  ]
}
state = Immutable.fromJS(state);
```

How can I modify this state, that is how can I append a new item so that I get this:

```
{ sequence: [
   [{column:3},{column:1}],
   [{column:3}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out using [setIn, mergeIn, updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/updateIn) etc. methods are very useful for nested structures:

```
let state = {
  sequence: [
    [{column:3}],
    [{column: 3}]
  ]
}
state = Immutable.fromJS(state);

const·item·=·Immutable.fromJS({column:·1});
const·nextState·=·state.updateIn(['sequence'],
                                     seq·=>·seq.push(item));
```

updates the item so it has this structure:

```
{ sequence: [
   [{column:3},{column:1}],
   [{column:3}]
}
```